# Line Segment is an edge of the Convex hull

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

I have to prove the following:

The line segment xz is an edge of the convex hull CH(A) iff all other points of A lie in one of the closed half-planes induced by the supporting line *l*(x, z) of xz, i.e., on (x, z) or to one side of the previous.

So far the only idea is to start somehow with the basics that a convex combination is a linear combination of points but no idea of the next step

Answer (score 0):

With a convex hull, all interior angles are less than $\pi$. This means if we enter a halfplane of $l(x,y)$, we must rejoin $l$ from the same halfplane, and so the other halfplane is out of bounds.

[image: convex hull]

If $l$ is the black line, the green line is okay, but the blue line isn't..